# Mat-Error not showing actual message in Reactive Forms when exceeding maxLength validation. Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I can see my validation for a textarea form control turning red when it exceeds 100 characters, however, the actual mat-error message is not showing up.  It works fine for a required validation. 
[EDIT] The correct answer is solved by the first answer below. "maxlength" is the syntax needed.

.ts

```
 descriptionFormGroup: FormGroup;
 descriptionCtrl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]);

 this.descriptionFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  descriptionCtrl: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]]
  });
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

HTML FILE

```
<form [formGroup]="descriptionFormGroup" class="center-flex-wrapper">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Description</ng-template>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput formControlName="descriptionCtrl" placeholder="Your Description" required [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"></textarea>
            <mat-hint>Max length is 100 characters</mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngIf="descriptionFormGroup.controls.descriptionCtrl.hasError('maxLength')">Max length exceeded</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="descriptionFormGroup.controls.descriptionCtrl.hasError('required')">Description is required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

Error State Matcher

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));}}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hasError string for maxLength is all lowercase.

So this

```
descriptionFormGroup.controls.descriptionCtrl.hasError('maxLength')
```

Should be:

```
descriptionFormGroup.controls.descriptionCtrl.hasError('maxlength')
```